# How to pass data to $mobile.changepage

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

```
$(".bTable tr").live('click', function(e){
    var bookno = $(this).attr("id"); 
    var bno = $("#"+ bookno +" .bookno").text(); 
    var cnt =  $("#"+ bookno +" .chapterCnt").text(); 

    var btitle =  $("#"+ bookno +" th h5").text(); 
    var btitle_eng =  $("#"+ bookno +" .eng").text(); 

    $.mobile.changePage("Pagecheck.html", {
                            type: "post",
                            data: "bno=" + bno +"&chapCnt="+cnt + "&btitle=" + btitle + "&btitleeng=" + btitle_eng
                        }
    ); // (1)

    e.stopImmediatePropagation(); 

});
```

Pagecheck.html code:

```
$('#Pagecheck').live('pageshow', function(e, ui) {
    var bno = getParameterByName('bno'); // (2) 
    var cno = getParameterByName('chapCnt'); 
    var btitle = getParameterByName('btitle'); 
    var btitleeng = getParameterByName('btitleeng');  

    subBookno = bno;   

    alert(bno); // (3) 
});
```

I'm making hybrid mobile app using Phonegap.
`(3)` alert's result is "null ".

What's wrong,  `(1)` or `(2)`?

Comment: Are you certain the parameter isn't empty? So, does `bno` actually contain a value, in your first code sample?

Comment: bno is'nt empty. certainly it has a value. this code works web brawser in pc, but doesn't work mobile app using phonegap.

Comment: Hi hyekyung, did you ever get to solve this?